# Javascript Date Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wonder if someone can help me solve an issue with Javascript.

I have some date code in which I define a start and end date, and then run a loop between those dates and add each date to an array, my code looks like;

```
var start_date = new Date("2021-07-01");
var end_date = new Date("2021-07-31");

var date_data = {};

var loop_date = new Date(start_date);

while(loop_date <= end_date)
{
   format_date = loop_date.toISOString().split('T')[0];
   date_data[format_date]; 
   var newDate = loop_date.setDate(loop_date.getDate() + 1);
   loop_date = new Date(newDate);
}
```

This produces me an array of dates under the variable "date_data" and works great.

I then have a set of data from a CSV that I load into the page, the CSV date looks something like

```
2021-05-22,OK,41,DONE
2021-06-12,OK,12,DONE
2021-07-03,OK,67,DONE
2021-07-24,OK,09,DONE
2021-08-14,NO,0,NOTDONE
```

The numeric values 12, 67 and 09 are whats important in this CSV (rows 2 - 4)

I then load the CSV data into a variable called "workload", and you will notice this data comes with dates set every 3 weeks apart.

What I want to do is run that date loop code and set a value from that CSV to each of the dates in the loop, so the final output of the code would look like

```
2021-07-01 = '12';
2021-07-02 = '12';
2021-07-03 = '67';
2021-07-04 = '67';
2021-07-05 = '67';
....
2021-07-21 = '67';
2021-07-22 = '67';
2021-07-23 = '67';
2021-07-24 = '09';
2021-07-25 = '09';
2021-07-26 = '09';
2021-07-27 = '09';
2021-07-28 = '09';
2021-07-29 = '09';
2021-07-30 = '09';
```

You will notice it sets the value from the CSV to the correct date in the array.

Then inside the loop I can simply do something like

```
date_data[format_date] = DATE_FROM_ARRAY;
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: _"and add each date to an array"_ - `date_data` is not an array. It's an object.

Comment: _"Can anyone help me with this?"_ - What's the actual problem? You have all you need in your question. You can generate a list of dates between two given dates. Use an actual array to store them. Think of a way to make it reusable (`function`), and find a way to pass the relevant _numeric value_ into that function. The last step would be to add the generated list in the correct spot.

Comment: Once you're using `var date_data = []` and `.push()` to get an actual array, keep a line marker that stores the current CSV line. In each loop iteration, check if the current date is the same as the date in the next CSV line and increase the CSV line marker by one if that's the case. Then use the number from the currently marked line and put it in the array.

Comment: See my [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68618569/295783)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it in 3 steps

Note: No tests for the start and end date actually present in the generated list

```js
const aDay = 24*60*60*1000;
// step 1, parse the CSV
const states = `2021-05-22,OK,41,DONE
2021-06-12,OK,12,DONE
2021-07-03,OK,67,DONE
2021-07-24,OK,09,DONE
2021-08-14,NO,0,NOTDONE`.split("\n").reduce((acc,line,cnt) => {
  const [date,status,num,doneornot] = line.split(",");
  acc[date] = num
  return acc
},{})

console.log(states);

// Step 2, generate the list of possible dates and values
const entryArr = Object.entries(states)
const datesVal = [];
for (let i=0;i<entryArr.length-1;i++) {
  const startDate = new Date(entryArr[i][0])
  const endDate = new Date(entryArr[i+1][0])
  const val = entryArr[i][1];
  for (let d = startDate.getTime(), n = endDate.getTime()-aDay;d<n;d+=aDay) {
    datesVal.push(`${new Date(d).toISOString().split('T')[0]}=${val}`)
  }
}

console.log(datesVal);

// Step 3, slice from start to end
const start_date = "2021-07-01";
const end_date = "2021-07-31";
const dateStart = datesVal.findIndex(item => item.startsWith(start_date));
const dateEnd = datesVal.findIndex(item => item.startsWith(end_date))

const dateList = datesVal.slice(dateStart,dateEnd+1);
console.log(dateList)
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you sir, top job